# Using a literal object as a Backbone.Model

Tags: backbone.js, view, model

I need to send a literal object to a view. Is there any better alternative to the following code:

```
var model= (new (Backbone.Model)).set({'foo':1,'bar':3})
```

Comment: you are creating a model and setting the values to it. i don't see any view as mentioned,edit and add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just simply

`var model = new Backbone.Model({'foo':1,'bar':3})`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you're just passing in some variables that are not relevant to the view data, then you should not be passing in a model. I can think of two other, more performant, ways to get data into your view.

#### Passing in data on instantiation

Every view will take parameter passed into the View constructor and hand them off the the view `initialize` (Backbone does a bit more with passed in parameters, but they all end up in `initialize`). Let me show you a trivial example.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    // All the parameter you pass into the view construct with will be
    // in the initialize options

    // Attach options to the view so you can access your options
    // from all view properties (bound to the view)
    this.options = options || {};
  }
}
```

Now get your object literal into your view:

```
var aView = new MyView({'foo':1,'bar':3});
aView.options.foo; // 1
aView.options.bar; // 3
```

#### Making data available after instantiation

If you want to merge an object *after* instantiation, then simply use `_.extend`:

```
_.extend(aView, {'foo':1,'bar':3});
aView.foo; // 1
aView.bar; // 3
```